# Amount in Words in Indian Format using Crystal Report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows

In Crystal Report i have the `sum{Total}` which is equal to `1128725.62`

Now i converted the money to Amount in words using following code

```
numberVar x :=(Sum({Command.Total}))- Int (Sum({Command.Total})) ;
    ProperCase (ToWords (Int (Sum({Command.Total})),0) + ', and ' + ToWords ((x * 100),0) + ' Paise Only')
```

It will display the the result as

```
One Million On Hundred Twenty-Eight Thousand Seven Hundred Twenty-Five , And Sixty-two Paise Only
```

Which is not in Indian Format, I actually needed the output as

```
Eleven Lakh Twenty-Eight Thousand Seven Hundred Twenty-Five , And Sixty-two Paise Only
```

What changes do i need to make Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I do not know any automatic way to use terms of the indian number system, I advise you to create a formula where the factors of certain power notations will be calculated explicitly (by division by powers of 10) and will be referred besides the appropriate name each time.

I give you an example to start for lakh and crore and you can keep on in case you meet in the future greater numbers

(forgive me if i am mistaken about numbers accuracy, I am not familiar with indian number system)

```
numberVar crorecount := Int(Sum({Command.Total})/10000000) ; //count of crores
numberVar lakhcount := Int(Int(Sum({Command.Total}) - (crorecount*10000000))/100000); //count of lakhs
numberVar decimal :=(Sum({Command.Total}))- Int (Sum({Command.Total})) ; //decimal part

stringvar croreSubStr := iif(crorecount>0,ToWords(crorecount,0)+' crore',''); //string you will add at the final result if number is greater of 10000000
stringvar lakhSubStr := iif(lakhcount>0,ToWords(lakhcount,0)+' lakh',''); //string you will add at the final result if number is greater of 100000

ProperCase (croreSubStr+' '+lakhSubStr+' '+ToWords (Int (Sum({Command.Total})-(crorecount*10000000)-(lakhcount*100000)),0) + ', and ' + ToWords ((decimal * 100),0) + ' Paise Only')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numberVar crorecount := Int({@Netamt}/10000000) ; //count of crores
numberVar lakhcount := Int(Int({@Netamt} - (crorecount*10000000))/100000); //count of lakhs
////numberVar decimal :=({@Netamt})- Int ({@Netamt}) ; //decimal part
stringvar croreSubStr := iif(crorecount>0,ToWords(crorecount,0)+' crore',''); //string you will add at the final result if number is greater of 10000000
stringvar lakhSubStr := iif(lakhcount>0,ToWords(lakhcount,0)+' lakh',''); //string you will add at the final result if number is greater of 100000
ProperCase (croreSubStr+' '+lakhSubStr+' '+ToWords (Int ({@Netamt})-(crorecount*10000000)-(lakhcount*100000),0)) +  'Only'
```